# Car key will not unlock car with buttons only with key after a battery change

Tags: electrical, key

My car key battery died. I changed it but now it won’t unlock my car with the buttons on the key but I can open the car with the key itself. It’s a Seat Alhambra 2.0 2006. The red light on the key does flash when the unlock/lock buttons are pressed.

Comment: Are you sure the battery died? The problem may be elsewhere, either in the key or in the car. Do you have two remote keys? If so, test the other key. This test determines whether the problem is in the key remote, or in the car. If the red light flashes, chances are the problem is in the car. I would start by checking the fuses.

Comment: I have only one key and the remote battery was dead as the light on the key didn’t work when the unlock button was pressed

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to re-pair the remote part of the key to the car.

Assuming it's the same on the 2006 as on the 2004 variety:

1. Insert key into driver’s door lock.
2. Turn the key to the unlock position 3 times and keep the key in the lock opening position for 5 sec.
3. Remove the key.

At this point the LED on the driver's door should illuminate solid red to show it's in "programming mode" - at this point you have about 15secs to do the following:

4. Press and hold the "lock" button.
5. Still pressing the "lock" button - press the "unlock" button 3 times (yes I know..fiddly isn't it?)
6. Release the lock button.

Now the LED on the door should flash to indicate that it's sync'd with the key. If you have any additional keys you need to repeat 4-6 for each of those (still within the 15sec window) as putting it in programming mode makes it forget all the existing remote fobs.

Comment: That’s with the type 1 key I have type 2 key and don’t have the type one key

Comment: @Algis Actually I think you're right - that's the procedure for the early versions of the radio key (the IR type is basically the same but you hold the key in the unlock position for less time).

Comment: @Algis I'll see if I can track down the one for the later type.